# Overflow-y messes with article and footer in responsive

Tags: css

So, I'm trying to make myself a front-end only website, and the HTML looks like this:

```html
<header>
  <p>Here is the header</p>
</header>
<section>
  <nav>
    <p>The menu goes here</p>
  </nav>
  <article>
    <p>Some text here</p>
  </article>
  <aside>
    <p>Some stuff here</p>
  </aside>
</section>
<footer>
  <p>A footer goes here</p>
</footer>
```

So how is it supposed to look: The header takes all the width on top, the menu is on the left, the article is the only thing scrollable and is on the center, and the aside has some stuff and is on the right. In the end, the footer is obviously meant to be on bottom of the website.

So I've made this CSS that works fine on desktop:

```css
body
{
 display: flex;
 height: 100vh;
 width:100%;
 flex-direction: column;
}

header
{
 height: 5vh;
}

header p
{
    font-size:4.2vh;
}

section
{
 display: flex;
 height: 100vh;
 flex-grow: 1;
}

article
{
 text-align: justify;
 max-height:91vh;
    text-justify: inter-word;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

aside
{
 width:210px;
}

footer
{
 height:3vh;
}

footer p
{
 font-size:2.2vh;
}
```

Therefore, the window will look the same no matter the size of the screen on desktop. However, in responsive, I did that :

```css
@media (max-width: 800px){
 section
 {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
 }
 
 header
 {
  height:initial;
  font-size:initial;
 }
 
 footer, footer p
 {
  height:initial;
  font-size:initial;
        bottom:0px;
        /*I try to fix it at the bottom of the page*/
 }
 
 nav
 {
  width:auto;
  flex-basis:auto;
 }
 
 article
 {
        /*There is actually a background for the website but the article's background is supposed to be white and to wrap the article's content. However, it does not.*/
  flex-grow:1;
  bottom:0;
  overflow-y:initial;
 }
 
    /* The aside is useless in responsive here */
 aside
 {
  display:none;
 }
}
```

But the footer is stuck in the middle of the article and the article overflows from his background.

Sorry if this is a super long post, but it's my first time posting here and I wanted to be sure everything was specific enough!

If you want to see how it is in action, go to http://neistuff.net

Comment: loooks okay to me, did you solve it?

Comment: The problem is with responsive. Try using `CTRL+SHIFT+M` on Firefox and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you are okay with a sticky footer:

```
footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Make sure you add some padding-bottom to the content though, so the footer do now show over the content :)

I'm not used to flex so I can not help you on the footer with flex. But there should be a solution for that with flex afaik.

Else, if you skip flex you can set html and body to 100% height and create a wrapper, set the footer absolute bottom 0 and set the padding bottom on the wrapper. Something like this: http://medda86.com/anime

Cheers :)

Comment: Actually if I do a position: fixed the background-color doesn't display somehow. Also the article background is still too short, so I guess I'll skip flex for this. I'll try and I come back to you, so stay tuned!